# The Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem for Manifold

Tags: differential-topology

I have read the paper *The Jordan-Brouwer Seperation Theorem* written by *Wolfgang Schmaltz*. The **main result** in paper is below

> Any compact, connected hypersurface $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$ will divide $\mathbb R^n$ into two connected regions; the *outside* $D_0$ and the *inside* $D_1$. Further more, $\bar{D_1}$ is itself a compact manifold with boundary $\partial\bar{D_1}=X$.

Now I am curious about the generalization of theorem. Can someone give any reference? Thank you in advance!

I also raise up one of my confusions:

> Consider the noncompact case. That is to say, we only assume $X$ is complete and connected. So $X$ may be not compact.

Can the theorem above still be right, if $D_0$ and $D_1$ are both unbounded?

Comment: Do you know about Poincare-Alexander duality for cohomology with compact support? Using it you get the same JB-separation conclusion in the noncompact case (instead of "complete" one usually says "properly embedded").

Comment: @Misha Is there any reference? Thank you.

Comment: A. Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".